# How do I configure an ASA 5505 to pull a DHCP address from a bridged DSL modem/router?

Tags: dhcp, cisco-asa

I have a remote office that I am hooking up to our corporate network and this particular site has a centurylink adsl2+ router that I need to negotiate an rfc 1483 via DHCP connection across.  The dsl modem is in bridged mode and it is connected to the outside interface on the ASA.  I need to configure the ASA to negotiate with the ISP to bring the interface up and pass traffic.

RFC 1483 via DHCP
multiplex set llc based Bridged mode
vpi:8  VCI:35
encapsulation ADSL2+

Any ideas on what the best ways to set this up are?

Comment: Whilst I have no idea myself, this guy seems to have done a bit of homework. Apparently it is not solved by PPPoE config, but what do I know. Perhaps you find something of use: http://www.farside.org.uk/200903/ipoeoatm

Comment: Erik,  that is an excellent little article and it totally covers what I need to do. I have to encapsulate my IP within ethernet frames as they go through my outside interface and land on the DSL modem.

Comment: That's what the DSL modem is doing.

Comment: I'm glad it was of use, user13846. If you wish to formulate your own answer with your specific solution I'll upvote.

Comment: So when I place the device in transparent bridging mode it will only pull an IP when I have the modem set to connect to the ISP first.  So there is a form of encapsulation that the cisco needs to package the IP packets in for it to properly go across the wire.  When I let the modem handle the encapsulation, the connection is really slow.  Painfully slow however it seems to pass traffic.

There are plenty of folks who were able to get this working with PPPoE and a username and password.  Unfortunately I have to use DHCP.

Running out of ideas here.

Answer (score 0):

```
interface (whatever)
 nameif outside
 pppoe client vpdn group CHN
 ip address pppoe
!
mtu outside 1492
!
vpdn group CHN request dialout pppoe
vpdn group CHN localname (your username)
vpdn group CHN ppp authentication pap (or whatever you need)
vpdn username (your username) (your password)
```

Reference: [Cisco "PIX/ASA: PPPoE Client Configuration Example" docs](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/security/asa-5500-x-series-next-generation-firewalls/110322-asa-pppoe-00.html)

Comment: You may want to suffix the `ip address pppoe` with `setroute` to say, well, set the route with that pppoe connection.  Also, "CHN" is an arbitrary name as far as I can tell, I'm just using what's in the docs

Comment: This ISP does not use a username or password.  It is supposed to pull the ip address and negotiate the connection automatically.  I looked around online to see if there were any specific configurations like this and did not see anything that was a perfect match.

Comment: Huh.  You use PPPoE but not auth?  Could you try just `ip address pppoe` on the appropriate interface and not the rest of it?

Comment: Reading that Cisco site, there's a comment above the `vpdn group CHN ppp authentication pap` line that says `If your ISP requires authentication, select an authentication protocol`.  I _think_ you can leave it out and it'll still work.

Comment: You could also (sorry about all the comments at once) try just turning on DHCP and see if it happens.  I doubt it, but it's possible?  What are their suggested settings for the DSL modem?

Comment: The ISP tells me the only setting that works is to configure it for RFC 1483 via DHCP.  Now as best as I can figure, the DSL modem is placed in a tansparent bridging mode where RFC 1483 is used as the transport and you have to establish a tunnel through the network to the ISP and that also involves pulling a DHCP address from the ISP.

Some configurations I have seen online require the cisco device to be configured with a dialer toto allow the encapsulation method to be established to get to the ISP.

Comment: So, how did straight DHCP work?  Or leaving the auth protocol out?